# Why not working java code?

Tags: java

```
package mainData;

public class Hello{
    public void Hello(String sData, int ... nAges){
        for(int x : nAges){
            System.out.println(sData + " " + x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Hello ages = new Hello("Age: ", 5, 6, 7, 8);
    }
}
```

When i change the **constructor**(Hello > Hello2) this code running without problem. But why this code not working?

Answer (score 9):

You are defining a method called `Hello` of return type `void`. A **[constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)** does *not* have a return type; use the following instead:

```
public Hello(String sData, int ... nAges) {
    for (int x : nAges) {
        System.out.println(sData + " " + x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: there is rarely a case where you should do much work in the constructor at all.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `void` from your constructor, [and it should work](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). [If you give a return type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8), then you are creating a method, not a constructor.

I suspect that your code *doesn't* run without a problem when you rename `Hello` to `Hello2`. It may compile and execute, but it won't print out the `nAges` arguments. Note that compilation isn't a sufficient test of correctness.